# Change Structure Permalink => Error 404? How to redirect

Tags: permalinks

i have a problem with Permalink as:
former, i have set Structure Permalink as: `/abc-%postname%/` now i change (remove `abc-`) and set Structure Permalink to `Post name as /%postname%/` but all my link is error 404.

Any idea for auto redirect Permalink `/abc-%postname%/` to `/%postname%/`

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a rule in your `.htaccess` (a file that will be in the root folder of your WordPress installation) - add this to the very bottom:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?abc-(.+)/?$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```